# Using Kafka instead of Redis for the queue purposes

Tags: apache-kafka

I have a small project that uses Redis for the task queue purposes. Here is how it basically works.

I have two components in the system: **desktop client** (can be more than one) and a **server-side app**. Server-side app has a **pull of tasks** for the desktop client(s). When a client comes, the first available task from the pull is given to it. As the task has an id, when the desktop client gets back with the results, the server-side app can recognize the task by its id. Basically, I do the following in Redis:

1. Keep all the tasks as objects.
2. Keep queue (pool) of tasks in several lists: **queue**, **provided**, **processing**.

When a task is being provided to the desktop client, I use RPOPLPUSH in Redis to move the id from the queue list to the *provided* list.

When I get a response from the desktop client, I use LREM for the given task ID from the *provided* list (if it fails, I got a task that was not provided or was already processed, or just never existed - so, I break the execution). Then I use LPUSH to add the task id to the *processing* list. Given that I have unique task ids (controlled on the level of my app), I avoid duplicates in the Redis lists.

When the task is finished (the result got from the desktop client is processed and somehow saved), I remove the task from the *processing* list and delete the task object from Redis.

If anything goes wrong on any step (i.e. the task gets stuck on the processing or provided list), I can move the task back to the queue list and re-process it.

Now, the question: is it somehow possible to do the similar stuff in Apache Kafka? I do not need the exact behavior as in Redis - all I need is to be able to provide a task to the desktop client (it shouldn't be possible to provide the same task twice) and mark/change its state according to the actual processing status (new, provided, processing), so that I could control the process and restore the tasks that were not processed due to some problem. If it's possible, could anyone please describe the applicable workflow?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible for kafka to act as a standard queue. Check the [consumer group](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Consumer+Group+Example) feature.

If the question is about the appropriateness, please also refer [Is Apache Kafka appropriate for use as a task queue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36206204/is-apache-kafka-appropriate-for-use-as-a-task-queue)

We are using kafka as a task queue, one of the consideration went in favor of kafka was that it is already in our application ecosystem, found it easier than adding one more component.